# How to describe the achievement of your subordinate

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, usage

what is the apt word that is to be used to describe the enthusiasm to learn and involve in work.

> Completed the assigned work well within the time and also proactive in
>   learning the subject.

Does the above statements make any sense, I would like to recommend his promotion also please give suggestions

Comment: Is there any reason to think this isn't correct? Why do you have doubts about this sentence?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a duplicate of the same question asked at [EL&U.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/493035/what-is-the-word-to-be-used-when-describing-your-subordinate-achievements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it, from the initial sentence of your question, that you are mostly asking about the word ***proactive***.

This word means deliberately doing things that may not yet be necessary, rather than just *reacting* to need. It means doing things so problems don't occur, and in your context it means learning things either before strictly necessary or without being told to do so. If that's what you're going for, then that's a very good word.

Other words that might be used, though with different meaning, might include ***enthusiastic*** to indicate that they were eager or well-engaged, happy to be learning, or ***self-led*** (which is a bit management-speak-ish, and I wouldn't recommend it) to indicate that they could lead themselves in the learning, not needing to be told what to learn and how to go about learning it. There are certainly other options available as well.

By the way, the sentence as a whole is good, although you don't need *also* as well as *and* - *and* is quite sufficient.